# What will replace RH Data Virtualization governance?

Tags: redhat-datavirt, data-governance

RH Data Virtualization 6.3 developer guide Volume 2 states that the governance component is deprecated. As we are interested in MDM/governance features, we would like to know if this component will be replaced or just dropped.
If dropped we are interested in alternative MDM solutions to complement RH DV.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the metadata is already available through SYSTEM metadata of the DV runtime server that was available in the governance repository before. There are plans for another centralized repository, but unfortunately, I do not have enough details.

I would be curious to know how you are planning to make use of this in your use cases?